# Unable to decode base64 python decode

Tags: python, base64, kodi

I'm working with Python (on a Kodi plugin). I manage to scrape a link which is in base64. I retrieve a link:

`aHR0cHM6Ly9jd3MwMDQuZ2VhcjNyZC5uZXQvZmlsZXMvdmlkZW9zLzIwMTcvMTAvMDIvMTUwNjg4NTg2ODQwNmY5LTI0MC5tcDQ/aD1STXc3aFUyZVU1anlkRHBnNWRuelB3JnR0bD0xNTA3MDc4NjU2.mp4`

which is stored in `source[0]`, however I can't seem to convert it to a decoded string?

For some reason below, where I find source[0], it won't decode? The line I think where the issue is: `b64s = base64.b64decode(source[0])`

```
def matplayer(url):
    page = get_url(url)
    source = re.findall("<iframe src='(.*?)'", page)
    if source:
        if 'youtube' in source[0]:
            return YoutubeOynat(url=source[0])
        elif 'dailymotion' in source[0]:
            return dailyoynat(url=source[0])
    else:
        source = re.compile('                file: "(.*?)"').findall(page)
        b64s = base64.b64decode(source[0])
        addLink(b64s,'','','')

def addLink(name,url,iconimage,description):
    ok=True
    liz=xbmcgui.ListItem(name, iconImage="DefaultVideo.png", thumbnailImage=iconimage)
    liz.setInfo( type="Video", infoLabels={ "Title": name } )
    liz.setInfo( type="Video", infoLabels={"Title": name,"Plot":description,})
    ok=xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=int(sys.argv[1]),url=url,listitem=liz)    
    return ok
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to decode something that does not need to be decoded. If you scraped it from the `src` attribute then it *is* the link.

Answer (score 1):

I just found your problem:
Your scrapped string is:

```
source = aHR0cHM6Ly9jd3MwMDQuZ2VhcjNyZC5uZXQvZmlsZXMvdmlkZW9zLzIwMTcvMTAvMDIvMTUwNjg4NTg2ODQwNmY5LTI0MC5tcDQ/aD1STXc3aFUyZVU1anlkRHBnNWRuelB3JnR0bD0xNTA3MDc4NjU2.mp4
```

I'll write code this way:

```
import base64
link = base64.b64decode(source.strip(".mp4"))

print(link)
```

In code above I have only decoded characters without extension `.mp4`
and the result is:

```
b'https://cws004.gear3rd.net/files/videos/2017/10/02/1506885868406f9-240.mp4?h=RMw7hU2eU5jydDpg5dnzPw&ttl=1507078656'
```